# Books that will cover TDD, DDD and Design Patterns in .NET

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, tdd, domain-driven-design, repository-pattern

I would like to get book(s) that will really give me a complete view of modern ASP.NET development using C#, TDD, ASP.NET MVC, DDD and Design Patterns such as the Repository pattern. I'm very competent with C# and ASP.NET MVC, but want to fill in the gaps.

If you've had a good experience with a book or two that covers these topics could you please share them?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm currently interested in how to architecture good .NET applications and I'm reading or have currently read some of the following books:

- [Design Patterns Explained: A New Perspective on Object-Oriented Design](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201715945)
- [Patterns of Enterprise Application Architecture](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321127420)
- [Microsoft .NET: Architecting Applications for the Enterprise](http://www.amazon.co.uk/exec/obidos/ASIN/073562609X/ref=ox_ya_oh_product)
- [Microsoft ASP.NET and AJAX: Architecting Web Applications](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Microsoft-ASP-NET-AJAX-Architecting-PRO-Developer/dp/0735626219/ref=pd_bxgy_b_img_b)

Those two Microsoft books really explain how to design .NET applications with high testability using Inversion Of Control and such.

And to be clear, yes they all use design patterns common in TDD, DDD, Dependency Injection, ans so on...

Comment: For anyone else striving to learn the DDD. Just made a quick recap of the books presented above. I would recommend you check the reviews for the books at first and then check the reviews validity. After doing that I come to a conclusion that none of the above books are worth my time. That is because the books are either too old or too deep and contradictory to be useful.

Answer (score 7):

["Domain Driven Design: Tackling Complexity in the Heart of Software"](http://books.google.lv/books?id=7dlaMs0SECsC&dq=domain+driven+design+eric+evans&printsec=frontcover&source=bn&hl=lv&ei=ynvVSo_LJMft-AaIytD_Ag&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=4&ved=0CBgQ6AEwAw#v=onepage&q=&f=false) by Eric Evans.

Comment: +1 This should be your key reference for DDD. But it will help a lot to have a working knowledge of the patterns described in Patterns of Enterprise Application Architecture first.

Answer (score 5):

Try [Applying Domain Driven Design and Patterns](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321268202) By Jimmy Nillson. It covers DDD and it's patterns in .NET

Comment: It's really a great book for someone with the questioner's background.

I helped proofreading the book, and gave it well deserved praise on its praise pages.

Recently, I had three collegues buy it, and no complaints so far ;-)

Comment: ADDDP gives some nice examples, and I liked that it took me through the logic behind the design decisions. But I felt at times the writing was a too conversational. It felt like the author was thinking out loud.

Comment: I thought this book was great too although I would like to see an updated revision of the book to make it a bit more current in terms of .NET with the advent of generics, dynamic types, lambda expressions, linq, MVVM and all of that.

Answer (score 4):

[Pro ASP.NET MVC Framework](http://www.apress.com/book/view/9781430210078) by Steve Sanderson includes the obvious ASP.NET MVC topic with C# as well as TDD, the Repository pattern, and domain modeling.  Good overview of all of these topics in one book.

For deeper coverage of DDD, i agree with Arnis L to get the bible ("Domain Driven Design: Tackling Complexity in the Heart of Software" ) by Eric Evans, and for a .NET specific view, I agree with Per Noalt on Applying Domain-Driven Design and Patterns: With Examples in C# and .NET.

[Pro ASP.NET MVC Framework http://www.apress.com/resource/bookcover/9781430210078?size=medium](http://www.apress.com/book/view/9781430210078)

Answer (score 3):

Guess the scope of topics you have asked is vast to be covered in a single book

Try this One [Agile Principles, Patterns, and Practices in C#](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0131857258) By Martin and Martin

Book talks mostly about Design Principles, Design Patters, UML Diagrams, Documentation, Refactoring. It doesn't cover ASP.NET and MVC though. YOu need to refer some other books for those.

Answer (score 2):

Here are a few that I would recommend:

- [Test Driven Development in Microsoft.NET](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735619484) by  James W. Newkirk and Alexei A. Vorontsov
- [Design Patterns in C#](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321126971) by Steven J Metsker
- [Professional ASP.NET MVC 1.0](http://www.wrox.com/WileyCDA/WroxTitle/Professional-ASP-NET-MVC-1-0.productCd-0470384611.html) by Rob Conery, Scott Hanselman, Phil Haack, Scott Guthrie

Answer (score 2):

For TDD try [xUnit Test Patterns](http://www.amazon.co.uk/xUnit-Test-Patterns-Refactoring-Signature/dp/0131495054/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&s=books&qid=1255510689&sr=8-1).

The best book I have read recently for filling in the gaps is [C# in depth](http://www.amazon.co.uk/C-Depth-What-need-master/dp/1933988363/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&s=books&qid=1255510861&sr=1-1) by Jon Skeet. It wasn't until reading this book that I realised how many gaps I had in my knowledge of C#.

Answer (score 2):

IMHO, Dependency Injection and TDD are working so nice together that I must add another book to the list:

- [Dependency Injection in .NET](http://manning.com/seemann/) by Mark Seemann (coming soon from Manning)

Answer (score 1):

For your needs I would recommend starting with:

- [Applying Domain-Driven Design and Patterns: With Examples in C# and .NET](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321268202)

Like the title says; it's basically a book on how to to DDD and TDD in a .NET environment.