# What are the list of Patterns and Principles a programmer must/should know?

Tags: design-patterns, design-principles

I have been coding for a few years and still feel that my knowledge is not broad enough to become a professional. I have studied some books related to design patterns, but I know there are many others.

So could somebody list the patterns and principles which you think are good to learn to become a better programmer and more professional?

Programming Languages I work on: C#, Ruby, Javascript.

Answer (score 8):

Encyclopedic knowledge of design patterns will get you nowhere. Plenty of **experience** applying them will. This will teach you when to use them and when not to.

That said, the original [Design Patterns](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201633612) book is still one of my favorites. Pick up other patterns as you go along.

Comment: *and when not to* - definitely the most important thing to remember. A lot of people seems to go patterns crazy at first and tries to make everything into patterns, sometimes making very easy code much more complex for no gain what so ever.

Answer (score 3):

Some of the more language-independent skills that I'm currently learning/working towards to improve my coding as a whole.

- Writing clean, readable and maintainable code
- Refactoring
- Proper object design for OOP languages
- Using a proper source control system correctly. Sourcesafe doesn't count :D
- Unit-testing & test-driven development
- Applying design patterns correctly. Learning them is one thing, learning when and where to apply them is much trickier.

Some links to book recommnendation questions @ SO:

- [What
  are the best design patterns books
  you have read?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/105049/what-are-the-best-design-patterns-books-you-have-read)
- [Help
  me pick a book on design patterns,
  refactoring, and/or testing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/529377/help-me-pick-a-book-on-design-patterns-refactoring-and-or-testing)
- [Books
  that will cover TDD, DDD and Design
  Patterns in .NET](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1563243/books-that-will-cover-tdd-ddd-and-design-patterns-in-net)
- [Best
  books about TDD](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31837/best-books-about-tdd)
- [Best design patterns book for a beginer?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1864899/best-design-patterns-book-for-a-beginer)
- [C#
  Design Patterns Book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/490807/c-design-patterns-book)
- [Good
  C# Unit testing book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/509445/good-c-unit-testing-book)

And of course, the [Pragmatic Programmer books](http://pragprog.com/) as mentioned in the earlier comment.

Comment: Thanks Mr Roys, any suggestion books for what you list?

Comment: I find the Pragmatic Bookshelf series very useful - http://pragprog.com/titles. As most in the series are quite short, they make good introductory texts too :) I believe there are quite a few posts on good books in SO, I'll try to find them and then edit the answer.

Answer (score 3):

The principles is where I'd start, with the patterns being a close second.

Principles: There's a whole raft, but these are the ones I get practical mileage from:

- [Single responsibility principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle) (SRP)
- [Separation of Concerns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns) (SoC)
- [Interface segregation principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interface_segregation_principle) (ISP)
- [Open/closed principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open/closed_principle)

A lot of these (when grouped together) are known as [SOLID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solid_(object-oriented_design)) (object-oriented design).

Patterns:

- My biggets favourite by a mile is the [Dependency Inversion Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_inversion_principle) (DIP), also commonly known as (or at least very similar to) [Inversion of control](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inversion_of_Control) (IoC).  It's really good for abstracting out data access implementations behind interfaces.  Martin Fowler calls it a different name (sorry don't have my copy of 'Patterns of Enterprise Application Architecture' in front of me).
- [Lazy Load](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_load) is also useful.
- [Factory pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_pattern) is a very well known one - for good reason.
- [Facade pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facade_pattern) has also helped me keep out of trouble.

Wikipedia has a pretty good list of [Software design patterns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Software_design_patterns), assuming you haven't seen it yet.

A final thing to keep in mind is that there are three basic types of patterns (plus a fourth category for multi-threaded / concurrency); it can help just to know about these categories and to bear them in mind when you're doing something, they are:

- Creational
- Structural
- Behavioral

Comment: I think Martin Fowler calls DIP as Dependency Injection (DI). http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection

Answer (score 2):

Mastering tools (e.g. programming paradigms, patterns, source control, unit tests...) is essential, but it's not enough to call yourself a "professional": IMHO, the mark of a truly professional programmer is the ability to understand what her client needs. Unfortunately, this kind of knowledge is very hard to learn from a book.

Answer (score 1):

I think the best way is to learn plenty of language.
LISP, Scheme, Python, Smalltalk, Erlang, Prolog, Eiffel and many others

And build stuff with them.

Answer (score 0):

Martin Fowler's [Patterns of Enterprise Application Architecture](http://martinfowler.com/books.html#eaa) to build up a shared vocabulary with other developers (e.g. Repository, Active Record, Domain Model, Unit of Work).

Douglas Crockford's [Javascript: The Good Parts](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596517742) to actually understand how Javascript works.

And I'd really recommend getting into TDD (Test Driven Development). There are a bunch of good TDD books but if you are doing brownfield development (which most of us are) then I'd really recommend Michael Feather's [Working Effectively with Legacy Code](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0131177052).

And finally the book that shows you just how refactored and clean code can be:
Uncle Bob's [Clean Code](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0132350882).

Answer (score 0):

In addition to writing code you should also try *reading* code. For example, download code from open source projects, try to tinker with it and understand what it's doing and why.
Or try reviewing your own code from a previous project. What would you do differently now? Can you still understand why you built it the way you did?

You may also want to look into some of the practices that have come out of the agile community. Especially [Test Driven Development](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test-driven_development) comes to mind as a great way to improve the quality of your code.

Answer (score 0):

I think, 
All the patterns described in the book **Head First Design Pattern** are the minimum that a designer/programmer must know. I suggest this book to start  learning design patterns.
Another book, **Design Pattern Work Book** is also good to practice.